# Get the Dataframe from temp view name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I can register a Dataframe in the catalog using

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_name")
```

I can check if the dataframe is registered

```
next(filter(lambda table:table.name=='my_name',spark.catalog.listTables()))
```

But how I can get the DataFrame associated with the name?

```
a_df = spark.catalog.getTempView()
assert id(a_df)==id(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spark.table() method will return the dataframe for the given table/view name

```
 a_df = spark.table('my_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
df=spark.sql("select * from my_name")
```

if you want to do some SQL before loading your df.